# Passing object parameter into multilevel child functions

Tags: vb.net, oop, object

I am looking for an elegant and efficient way of passing object parameter into multilevel child functions.

`SyncTask` in an entry point.

```
Public Class

Public Sub SyncTask(log As TextWriter)
    SyncJob1(log)
    SyncJob2(log)
    SyncJob3(log)
    SyncJob4(log)
End Sub

Private Sub SyncJob1(log As TextWriter)
    ' Do some job
    AddToLog(log, log_message As String)
End Sub

Private Sub AddToLog(log As TextWriter, log_message As String)
    ' transform log_message and log it into log object and also database
End Sub

End Class
```

The only solution I found out is adding at class level `Private MyLog As TextWriter` and `MyLog = log` into SyncTask method, so child functions will not have to pass `log` further and `AddToLog` method will be able to use class level `MyLog`.

However I do feel this is not an elegant nor clear solution.

I use Visual Studio 16.6.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that approach.  Especially since SyncJob(1-4) are private and you'd only be calling the main SyncTask.  That's an excellent solution.

Comment: Both solutions are valid, my only comment is using a class level variable is saves you a little typing where as passing it through as parameters is a little more descriptive.  I would say horses for course on this one

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it by reference. When you pass a variable by reference, instead of a copy of the variable, you actually use the original one (it doesn't work with primitives, though).

```
Public Sub SyncTask(ByRef log As TextWriter)
    SyncJob1(log)
    SyncJob2(log)
    SyncJob3(log)
    SyncJob4(log)
End Sub

Private Sub SyncJob1(ByRef log As TextWriter)
    ' Do some job
    AddToLog(log, log_message As String)
End Sub
```

Or you can return it:

```
Public Function SyncTask(log As TextWriter) As TextWriter
    log = SyncJob1(log)
    log = SyncJob2(log)
    log = SyncJob3(log)
    log = SyncJob4(log)

    Return log
End Sub

Private Function SyncJob1(log As TextWriter) As TextWriter
    ' Do some job
    AddToLog(log, log_message As String)

    Return log
End Sub
```

Both methods will work if you decide to make these Shared functions. If you don't need that kind of manipulation, a modal variable (at class level like you already tried) will get the job done, but yes, it's better to have only modal variables which makes sense for your class and not some variable thrown there because you wanted to accomplish one thing at a specific place and which makes no sense with the rest of the class.

(Dont' forget to use the same method with `AddToLog` too.)

Have fun!